# Perl hash + while loop

Tags: perl, hash, while-loop

I am new here and pretty new to programming. For better or worse, I decided to use Perl as a way to break into coding.

My question concerns the following Perl code:

```
my $name;
my %phonenumbers = (
    "Gary" => "0001",
    "Ian"  => "0002",
    "Nick" => "0003",
);

my $numbers = reverse $name;

print "Whose phone number do you want?\n";
my $selection = <STDIN>;
while ( $selection ne $phonenumbers{$name} ) {
    chomp;
    print "$_ is not in my database. Try another name";
} else {
    print "$_: $phonenumbers{$name}";
}
```

I want it to stay in the loop and ask for a correct name if an incorrect name is given. Otherwise I want it to display the correct phone number. Right now it stays in the loop no matter what.

I've tried using if and until instead, but no luck.Could someone explain what I am missing?

Comment: You're only checking `<STDIN>` once - you need to query it again.

Comment: chomp selection right after reading it, for starters

Answer (score 2):

Create an infinite loop and break out of it using [`last`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html) if the input matches your desired conditions.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %phonenumbers = (
    "Gary" => "0001",
    "Ian"  => "0002",
    "Nick" => "0003",
);

while (1) {
    print "Whose phone number do you want?\n";
    chomp( my $name = <STDIN> );

    if ( $phonenumbers{$name} ) {
        print "$name: $phonenumbers{$name}";
        last;
    } else {
        print "$name is not in my database. Try another name";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to repeatedly ask for the number, you need to include it in your loop; otherwise `$selection` will never get any new values from the user. I typically like an infinite loop that you break out of for situations like this. Also, I think you really want `$phonenumbers{$selection}` not `$phonenumbers{$name}`:

```
# infinite loop version
my $selection; 
NUMBER:
while ( 1 ) {
   print "Whose phone number do you want?\n";
   $selection = <STDIN>;
   chomp($selection);     # need to specify variable to chomp

   # if the name exists in the "database" print the phonenumber and exit the loop
   if ( exists $phonenumbers{$selection} ) {
      print "$selection: $phonenumbers{$selection}\n";
      last NUMBER;
   }

   # otherwise, the name is not in the database; print error message
   print "$selection is not in my database. Try another name.\n";
}
```

You could also use a variant of this that uses a variable to keep the loop moving:

```
# boolean flag version
my $selection; 
my $valid_number = 0; # false

while ( !$valid_number ) {
   print "Whose phone number do you want?\n";
   $selection = <STDIN>;
   chomp($selection);     # need to specify variable to chomp

   # if the name exists in the "database" print the phonenumber and exit the loop
   if ( exists $phonenumbers{$selection} ) {
      print "$selection: $phonenumbers{$selection}\n";
      $valid_number = 1; # true
   } 
   else {
      # otherwise, the name is not in the database; print error message
      print "$selection is not in my database. Try another name.\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've rewritten your program with comments. I hope it helps.

- I assume `my $numbers = reverse $name` is spurious?
- *Always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program. It will save you untold time debugging and fixing your program
- No need to use such lengthy identifiers. They must be meaningful, but you will start to get irritated the fortieth time you have to type `phonenumbers`!
- Remember to `chomp` your input. Unless you have changed the record separator or you are reading the last line from a file, *everything* you read using `readline` - better known as `<>` - will have a newline at the end
- You are missing the point of hashes, and it's a delightful *Ah!* moment when you get them. Hashes are *indexed by their key*, so in the same way as you can access the first element of an array with `$array[0]`, you can access Ian's phone number using `$phonenumbers{Ian}`. That's it. There's no need to loop over the keys to find the one you want
- Your `while` loop needs to chnage the test, and yours doesn't. You compare `$selection` to `$phonenumbers{$name}`, and if they are different you `chomp $_` (a `chomp` without a parameter operates on `$_`) and print a message. Neither change either of the values you are comparing, so your loop would loop forever ...
- ... if, that is, your syntax was correct. A `while` can have a `continue` block after it (but don't worry about that) but an `else` isn't valid so your program doesn't compile.

Those points mostly explain the changes I have made to your program, but here's the rest

- The *fat comma* operator `=>` is useful because it visually ties values together in pairs. As a list, a hash is just `key, value, key, value...` so it's useful in that way. But it *also* puts implicit quotes around anything before it that could be an identifier. That means I can write, for example, `gary => '0001'` instead of `'gary' => '0001'`
- I have used `$phones{lc $choice}` to access the hash. The `lc` operator returns its operand as a string in all lower-case. That means that `$choice` can be `Gary` or `gary` or `GARY` or even `garY` to locate the same hash element
- Rather than asking again and again for a phone number that doesn't exist, I've changed it so that the program calls `die` if there is no such phone. Fixing it to do more is a big step, as you have to let the user give up somehow as well as looking for more names.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $name;
my %phones = (
   gary  => '0001',
   ian   => '0002',
   nick  => '0003',
);

print "Whose phone number do you want: ";
my $choice = <STDIN>;
chomp $choice;

my $number = $phones{lc $choice};
die "$choice is not in my database. Try another name" unless defined $number;

print "$choice: $number\n";
```

Comment: Thanks. That helps me see the bigger picture.